# How to put spacing between table cells in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm trying to duplicate the style of this employee plaque as seen here, but only how they are doing the table of names:
http://www.fusionframes.com/products/EOM-Window-Mat-Burl-Plaque-Frame-Black-%26-Gold.html

I'm having difficulty with HTML in figuring out how to have the gold cells separated so the black background comes through and the black is around the outside of the table. I have adjusted cellspacing and that doesn't do it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<table border="40" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color:#000000" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<TR><TD>

<table border="20" bordercolor="#A67100" style="background-color:#F1F1D4" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>Jan 2014<BR>Name 1</td>
        <td>Dec 2013<BR>Name 2</td>
        <td>Nov 2013<BR>Name3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `cellspacing="15"` to get space between each table cells

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCm87/15/)

Comment: That doesn't allow the black background to come through. Can you provide a working HTML example of this?

Comment: @Edward : wait. i will post in fiddle

Comment: If you look at the link in the posting, it shows the black between the cells. I want to make it look like that. Thanks.

Comment: @Edward : its very simple mate. you should mention the background color like this **td{background:#F1F1D4;}**..http://jsfiddle.net/KCm87/17/

Comment: I'm getting this now, thanks! One last thing, how do I get rid of the white border that's around the gold?